# How to use dash and dot characters in android:name in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, mobile, android-manifest

For my Android app, I need to add the following property into `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name="de.myapp.My-App.de">
```

The name of the project is "My-App.de". I know that using dashes and dots here is no good idea but I can't change it. The product owner wants it called like this.

Since I get an error message, I simply escaped the dash with a "\" character which leads to this name:

```
<application android:name="de.myapp.My\-App.de">
```

Is this correct? Must the very last dot be escaped too?

Comment: Did any answer help? Don't forget to accept the one that worked for you, so the next one searching it will find the answer more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why not using `android:label`?

Just a sidenote. If your client told you to use a plutonium keyboard instead of a regular keyboard, would you accept it? Sometimes (almost every time) we have to rid with clients that doesn't have the same background we do, specially when coming to Computer Science. If something can't be done (or shouldn't or whatever), you should convice your client. You can give them many reasons: the system is less secure or could be compromised, the application becomes unstable, what the client wants could be done in an easier to understand way, etc.

At least in my company, I am paid to develop **AND** to give advice, and even if I talk to a client, I tend to ensure they understand the implications of what they want and know what can't be done and what should be done instead.

**Edit:**

Some resources:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm

Name is a **fully qualified name for an Application subclass**. As you may know, classes aren't to be written with dashes. We are all aware that Android's naming convention is not the most accurate in the world, so problems like this always arise. Try adding to the already defined by default `@string/app_name` a dash. I am not in front of my Android projects, but it should work as well. If it doesn't, try enclosing the string with a CDATA markup:

```
<string name="app_name"><![CDATA[de.myapp.My-App.de]]></string>
```

This avoids xml escaping the text (which should not be necessary, but who knows).

Comment: It's not the client who wants this. It's my boss, the product owner.

Comment: Also, android:label doesn't work. I used in the manifest @string/full_app_name as value but it still complains because of the dash character.

Comment: Your boss acts as a client, and thus can be treaten equally. See my edits for some clarification

Answer (score 2):

In your `strings.xml` under the `res/values` folder, you can add your app name like so:

```
<string name="app_name">de.myapp.My-App.de</string>
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you can reference it:

```
<application android:name="@string/app_name">
```

This will allow your app name to have dashes.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but it won't work. I still get a parser exception that states it doesn't like the dash character.

Comment: That's weird. I just tried it with my app and there were no errors. Maybe you are using dashes in another spot as well?

Comment: This is completely crazy. I have another string in strings.xml with a dash in it this one works. I really don't get this...

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on. In AndroidManifest.xml, if I use android:label="app_name" it works but for android:name it seems like it doesn't like the string value.

Comment: Why are you using android:name to begin with? It's an optional paramater according to android documentation.

If you are trying to set the app name, you should be using android:label

Comment: Not only that. It's not meant to work as a name as we use to think. See my answer

Comment: @valmar See android documentation [link here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm), as you can see it's an optional paramater.

It seems your product owner wants the app name to have a dash, you should switch `<application android:name="@string/app_name">` with `<application android:label="@string/app_name">` using the process I posted and you'll achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to store your appname in the string.xml and encode the special character - (dash) and . (dot) to unicode you can refer the unicode in here -> http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0

For example .My\u002DApp\u002Ede

Comment: Do you have an example for encoding the special character with unicode? I stored the value in strings.xml but if I reference it via @string/full_app_name I still get a parser error which complains because of the dash character.

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:name="de.myapp.My-App.de"> is not correct.
```

You just use

```
<application android:name="Package_name.Application_class_name">
```

Where name's of package and class must